# Why does $router.push({ name: 'summoner', params: { summonerName: summonerName }}) leads to url /summoner/username/ instead of /summoner/username?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to execute a function that redirects the user to another page when he clicks a certain element, however,

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'matchlist', params: { summonerName: summonerName }})
```

leads to URL `/summoner/username/` instead of to `/summoner/username`. If you haven't noticed, there's a backtick at the end of the first URL which causes a problem which doesn't exist if I'm on `/summoner/username`

If I use this:

```
this.$router.push({ path: `/summoner/${summonerName}` })
```

I get sent to `/summoner/username` and everything works fine BUT I'm still curious why I get that backtick in the first example.

Routes:

```
{
    path: '/summoner/:summonerName',
    component: Summoner,
    children: [
        { path: '', component: Matchlist, name: 'matchlist' },
        { path: 'match/:matchId', component: SpecificMatch, name: 'specificMatch' }
    ]
}
```

Function:

```
    redirectToProfile(participant){
        let summonerName = participant.identity.player.summonerName
        this.$router.push({ name: 'matchlist', params: { summonerName }})
        //this.$router.push({ path: `/summoner/${summonerName}` })
    },
```

Comment: Is this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1753) related?

Comment: Sadly the jsfiddle that is supposed to contain the answer won't open for me.

Comment: Yea, JSFiddle is unhappy right now :/

Comment: _"Backtick"_? Do you mean forward-slash, ie `/`? A backtick (also known as grave) is `\``

Comment: You've got `{name: 'summoner'}` in your call to `push()` but your route does not have that (or any) name

Comment: Oh my bad, I did mean a forward-slash. And it seems that I wrote the wrong component name as you have pointed out, but that is only on here and not in the actual code. I did correct it now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a discussion about the issue on github https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1753

And the solution is to add `pathToRegexpOptions: { strict: true }` to your routs.

A fiddle by Josh Deltener which shows an example: http://jsfiddle.net/L7hscd8h/9377/